# using core data variable to specify font size

Tags: ios, core-data, floating-point, uifont

I've got a variable in my Core Data model set to the float type called "speech1Size".   I'm trying to use that variable to set the font size of a UILabel, but I'm getting errors each way I try it.

Running the following example returns this error:
"Method '+fontWithSize:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')"

```
// first I get the value
NSNumber *fontSize = [detailViewController.detailItem valueForKey:@"speech1Size"];

// try to set the UILabel's font size
detailViewController.speech1Label.font = [UIFont fontWithSize:fontSize];
```

I've tried a variety of other things like casting as float, but that returns an error and this seems closest so far.  I realize I'm missing something simple...Thank you for your time!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `fontWithSize` method is an instance method, and you are trying to use it as a class method. Maybe you wanted to use `+fontWithName:size:`.

Also, the size parameter is expected to be a CGFloat value. Try passing `[fontSize floatValue]`.

Comment: Thank you for the fabulous answer!    It works now that I've done this:   `NSNumber *fontSize = [detailViewController.detailItem valueForKey:@"speech1Size"];
    CGFloat fontSizeToUse = [fontSize floatValue];
    detailViewController.speech1Label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Chalkduster" size: fontSizeToUse];`